# VB.NET Abstract Property

Tags: vb.net

I have an abstract "GridBase" class with two types of derived classes "DetailGrid" and "HeaderGrid".

Respectively, one is comprised of "DetailRow" objects and the other "HeaderRow" objects. Both of those inherit from a "RowBase" abstract class.

What I am trying to do is the following:

```
Public MustInherit Class GridBase
    Private pRows As List(Of RowBase)

    Public ReadOnly Property Rows As List(Of RowBase)
        Get
            Return pRows
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DetailGrid
    Inherits GridBase
End Class
```

In this scenario, I want DetailGrid.Rows to return a list of DetailRow. I want HeaderRow.Rows to return a list of HeaderRow. Am I on the right track with this or should the Rows property not be included in the GridBase class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a stronger typing guarantee, then you probably want:

```
Public MustInherit Class GridBase(Of T as RowBase)
    Private pRows As List(Of T)

    Public ReadOnly Property Rows As List(Of T)
        Get
            Return pRows
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class DetailGrid
    Inherits GridBase(Of DetailRow)
End Class
```

Comment: Excellent. That worked as I needed it. Thanks for the quick reply. How come the T is picked up in the property? It's shared throughout the entire class? So if you wanted to do this with a second property you couldnt?

Comment: there is no magic to 'T'.  For a second List you can use`As List(Of TT)`